# Convolution padding at border rows and columns

Tags: image-processing, filtering, convolution

I am trying to convolute an image of `4x5`  with filter of `3x3`, I need a result image in the same size, i.e., `4x5`.

How can I pads border rows and columns for border extension?

```
  int kernel[3][3] = {{1,2,1},{2,4,2},{1,2,1}};

    for( int i=0;i<imgWidth;i++)
         for(int j=0;j<imgHeight;j++){

        float sum = 0;
            for(int r = -1;r<2;r++)
               for(int t = -1;t<2;t++)
            {
                      float intensity;
                     if(r+i<0 || r+i>imgWidth || j+t < 0||j+t>imgHeight )//boundry check
                        intensity = 0;
                      else 
                        intensity = loadedImage->GetRed(i+r,j+t);
                        sum += intensity *((float)1/16);
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add rows and columns to your image (in which case we'll need to know what language you're using), or are you asking what values to put in those new rows and columns (in which case it depends on your image and what you're trying to achieve with the convolution).

Comment: I am implementing convolution in c++ and I need to Duplicate rows and columns for border extension but my question here is how to implement this border extension. during convolution we loop over image using filter 3*3.

Comment: In that case, showing us your code for creating your image array and your attempt at padding the array would be appropriate.

Comment: I just realized this was a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323372/how-to-duplicate-the-border-rows-and-columns-for-border-extension. If your question is not getting any attention, it's probably because it needs clarification. Re-posting the same question with no new information doesn't help. I also notice that you haven't accepted any of the answers given to your previous questions. If you're not going to accept answers, there is very little incentive for people to help you  with new questions.